# Uninstall google earth pro redux

Tags: google-earth

Installed google earth *pro* and cannot find any solution on how to totally purge this from my ubuntu Jammy system.  All the instructions and help are for google earth stable, not pro.  I need to install because whenever I run apt-get update I have errors about .... "configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth-pro.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d"

So I'll just get rid of it and start over.  It is located in /opt/google/earth/pro/

Thanks any help much appreciated.

Comment: So open the /etc/apt/sources.list.d and remove the line for the app. If there is any directory in /etc/apt/sources.list for the app remove that as well. This takes care of the error. If you want to remove the app that is a different question. First need to know the exact command used to install it. Please use edit and add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt remove google-earth-pro-stable
```

or

```
sudo apt purge google-earth-pro-stable
```

which will purge also all configuration data from your disk.